# curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" "localhost:1337/webhook" not working

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, curl, chatbot

I am working to create a facebook chatbot using the webhook service and came to know about the link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started/quick-start.

I am able top got up to the `curl -X` but the next command `curl -H` is not working and giving the error as

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0
>   
>    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
>     at
>   createStrictSyntaxError
>   (C:\Users\amit\messenger-webhook\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:158:10)
>      at parse
>   (C:\Users\amit\messenger-webhook\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)
>      at
>   C:\Users\amit\messenger-webhook\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
>      at invokeCallback
>   (C:\Users\amit\messenger-webhook\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
>      at done
>   (C:\Users\amit\messenger-webhook\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
>      at IncomingMessage.onEnd
>   (C:\Users\amit\messenger-webhook\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
>      at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
>     at
>   IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
>     at
>   endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)  
>   curl: (6) Could not resolve host: page, curl: (6) Could not resolve
>   host: entry curl: (3) [globbing] bad range specification in column 2
>   curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 13

Comment: You're sending an invalid JSON, show your full `curl`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Marcos. I have done the same procedure as described in the link. Please see the link and you will know the whole process.

Comment: I don't see any curl in there, so post the full `curl` command in here if you want help, all the information must be present in the question, not in an external link.